# Repeating a function inside a function in a class

Tags: python

I am a beginner how can I fix my problem which I want to repeat another function before it is called

This is my code:

```
class Banking:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.balance = 0

    def intro (self):
        print ('Welcome to Banking and services')

    def deposit (self):
        dep = float (input ('Enter amount to be deposited: '))
        self.balance += dep

    def withdraw (self):
        wthdrw = float (input ('Enter amount to b withdrewn: '))
        if wthdrw > self.balance:
            print ('Insufficient balance')
        else:
            self.balance -= wthdrw
            print ('You have the remaining,', self.balance, "Net Amount Balance")

    def again (self):
        while True:
            agn = input ('New transaction? (yes/no)').lower().strip()
            if agn == 'no':
                print ('Ok, bye have a great day')
                break
            elif agn == "yes":
                intro (self)
                deposit (self)
                withdraw (self)
                again (self)

    bank = Banking()
    bank.intro()
    bank.deposit()
    bank.withdraw()
    bank.again()
```

When I run the code the output from intro to withdraw is ok but when it comes to again it say that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tnp_10ten.py", line 36, in <module>
    bank.again()
  File "tnp_10ten.py", line 27, in again
    intro (self)
NameError: name 'intro' is not defined
```

Comment: In python, you should reference class methods by `self`. So change your code from `intro (self)` to `self.intro()`.

Comment: Also, not the bug you are asking about, but a bug still: remove `again` call in the again function, there's already a `while True` loop, no need for recursion here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix to again function:

```py
def again (self):
        while True:
            agn = input ('New transaction? (yes/no)').lower().strip()
            if agn == 'no':
                print ('Ok, bye have a great day')
                return
            elif agn == "yes":
                self.intro()
                self.deposit()
                self.withdraw()
```

As others explained, you need to use self.func() to reference the current classes function.
Also, you need to return if user inserts 'no' and not break. Breaking will result in neeeding to insert 'no' the same amount of times you said 'yes' before.

Comment: Actually remove `self.again()` from the `again` function, there's already a `while True`, no need for recursion here.

Answer (score 0):

When calling functions from the same class you need to use `self.`

So in your `again` function you need to change

```
intro (self)
deposit (self)
withdraw (self)
again (self)
```

to

```
self.intro()
self.deposit()
self.withdraw()
```